# MySQL max_connections

Tags: mysql

I have setup with Linux, Debian Jessie with Mysql 5.7.13 installed.

I have set following settings in

`my.cnf: default_storage_engine= innodb, innodb_buffer_pool_size= 44G`

When I start MySQL I manually `set max_connections` with `SET GLOBAL max_connections = 1000;`

Then I trigger my loadtest that sends a lot of traffic to the DB server which mostly consists of slow/bad queries.

The result I expected was that I would reach close to 1000 connections but somehow MySQL limits it to 462 connections and I can not find the setting that is responsible for this limit. We are not even close to maxing out the CPU or Memory.

If you have any idea or could point me in a direction where you think the error might be it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What loadtest did you use? Are you sure that it can utilize about thousands of connections?

You may maxing out your server resources in the disk IO area, especially if you're talking about lot of slow/bad queries. Did you check for disk utilization on your server?

Even if your InnoDB pool size is large your DB still need to read your DB to the cache first, and if your entire DB is large it will not help you.

I can recommend you to perform such a test once more time and track your disk performance during loadtest using iostat or iotop utility.

Look [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/view/troubleshooting-steps-for-when-your-hard-disk-is-giving-you-trouble.html) for more examples of the server performance troubleshooting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue, it was du to limitation of Apache server, there is a "hidden" setting inside /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/mpm_prefork.conf which will overwrite setting inside /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Thank you!